# Concrete5: index external links and show in search results of search box

Tags: concrete5

In Concrete5, how can I enable external links to 1) be indexed, and 2) show up in the search results, using the search block. I guess point 2 will automatically happen when 1 works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to tap into the C5 search index in any way other than via blocks on a page or page properties (custom attributes). This means you cannot add external links to the search index in C5 because the pages that are linked to are not part of your site and hence have no concrete5 blocks on them, and also you can't set custom attributes on external links (although actually there is a roundabout way to do so, via the "Page Search" dashboard page -- but I have a feeling this is a bug in the system because setting those attributes doesn't actually do anything as far as I can tell).

Comment: So if I understand correctly,page properties (which can also be set for external links in the search pages menu) are not indexed? Or is there a way to do that?

Comment: You are correct that page properties (custom attributes) can also be part of the search index (if the "Content included in sitewide page search index" box is checked when you define the attribute in the dashboard). And I wasn't aware that you could set those on external links, but I now see what you mean. Unfortunately in my testing, setting the custom attributes on external links had no effect on the search index, so I think it's one of those rough edges of the system that does not work as you'd expect. I've updated my answer to reflect this -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The concrete5 search index goes over blocks which are included in concrete5 pages and looks in their BlockController instances for indexable content.

In detail, it does these two things:

1. Checks which areas are searchable. The areas can be configured in
   your concrete5 dashboard at Systems and Settings > SEO and
   Statistics > Search Index
2. It goes through all blocks in these areas, and looks for the
   function **getSearchableContent() in your block controller**.
   Whatever this function returns will be indexed, and then it will
   show up in the search if the MySql like search matches it or other
   strings from blocks on the same page.

Look for this function, or add it if it's not there

```
public function getSearchableContent() { 
    return $this->yourTitle . ': ' . $this->yourExternalLink;
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question -- there is no way to add blocks to an external link so this technique is not relevant in this situation.

Comment: I'm sorry I guess I misunderstood the question then, but external links can be indexed through blocks, so I thought that was what you meant

Comment: I'm not the person who asked the question, so I can't say for sure what they meant. But can you clarify your statement about indexing external links through blocks? If that is indeed a solution to the problem, you should explain exactly how it is you can achieve that (I've never seen this technique so I'd be very interested to learn more about it as well).

Comment: The way you index external links is described indirectly in my answer. You need a block which for example stores external links in a field field, let's call the field "yourExternalLink". Then in your blockController, you use the getSearchableContent() function to return that string to the c5 indexer, and voila, your external links will be indexed.

Comment: I think we have different interpretations of what is being asked. I'm thinking they have external links as part of their sitemap and they want to index the *content* of those external links (so a link to the external page will show up in the search results). This is unfortunately not possible in C5 because the search index only lists site pages (not external links). But it seems that you are interpreting this as the OP having a page with a bunch of links on it and wanting the anchor text of those links to be indexed -- which your solution will solve (but so will the built-in "content" block).

Comment: The interpretation of Jordan Lev was correct. What I noticed is that you can add page properties to an external link. If those could be indexed and search, that would go a long way to solve the issue of being able to find external links based on a description or key words of their content.